# sed or awk command to merge two line into a single line

Tags: linux, shell, awk, sed

I have a text file with the following format.

**12345**

**abcdefg**

I need this to be in the same line. So the output should look like this...

**12345 abcdefg**

How should i proceed ? using **sed** or **awk** ?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to join every `line[i]` and `line[i+1]` with a space,
you could use `paste`:

```
paste -d' ' - - < file
```

Answer (score 0):

For given input and expected output below one should work

Using [`xargs`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/xargs.1.html)

```
$ cat infile
12345
abcdefg

$ xargs < infile
12345 abcdefg
```

Using [`tr`](http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_man_pages/tr1.html)

```
$ tr -s '\n' ' ' <infile ; echo
12345 abcdefg
```